# HTML+CSS: transparent sticky that clips everything but the background. Is that possible w/o JS?

Tags: html, css

See this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vkxdshoL/

I have a translucent page with a background and I want this to shine though my sticky element. But I dont want the text to shine trough. There is a javascript solution to that by doing something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var clipPos = -content.getBoundingClientRect().top + header.clientHeight;
  content.style.clipPath = "inset(" + clipPos + "px 0 0 0)";
});
```

But i'd rather have my page without any additional JS. Is there a pure HTML/CSS solution for clipping the text?

HTML:

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
  <header>
    <p>…</p>
  </header>
  <article>
    <header>Should be sticky, but clip text</header>
    <p>…</p>
    <p>…</p>
    <p>…</p>
    <footer>This should be at the bottom</footer>
  </article>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: justify;
  background: url(…);
  color:#fff;
  background-size: cover;
}
article {background:#4000;}
article > header {
  background:#c8f8;
  position:sticky;
  height:2rem;
  top:0;
}
article > footer {
  background:#cf88;
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
}
```